# Google maps showing error Api project not authorised

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, geolocation

I'm implementing google maps where I'm passing address to google maps api to get current location on map, but it is showing following error in browser console,

```
 This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/geocoding_backend?project=_ For more information on authentication and Google Maps Javascript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
```

Also I want to use google maps api on server side, to fetch latitude and longitude based on provided address.
I am new to implement google maps api, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994634/this-api-project-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-please-ensure-that-this-api

Answer (score 2):

you should register to google map api from [https://developers.google.com/maps/](https://developers.google.com/maps/get-started/).

select the specific api for you

click on Get a Key

Then Create a new project

Activate the Google Maps JavaScript API

copy you key and put it in the api url you are using in your code

if the api did not respond you need to add a domain on which you are working and then

Done!

Comment: How to Activate the Google Maps JavaScript API

Comment: you can find different code snippets for each of the api you choose, then you can customize it by changing, adding or removing some js attributes.