# Google Map Service API did not work in Python

Tags: python, api, google-maps

I am developing model to calculate origin to destination using **Python3**. I tried `google-maps-services-python` from **github** and obtain an error.

```
[API Key already enabled][1]

ApiError: REQUEST_DENIED (This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console:)
```

However the same key I tried work as `http` request over browser.

```
The API key did not apply any key restriction
[API key did not apply any key restriction][2]
```

Any idea what need to be done?

Comment: Maybe take a look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994634/this-api-project-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-please-ensure-that-this-api). Cheers.

Comment: I checked repeatly where the API was activated and it worked over web browser. Thanks @orvi anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994634/this-api-project-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-please-ensure-that-this-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULwrH.jpg)

In order to make it direct query from IPython, you need both API enabled.

-Google Maps Directions API

-Google Maps Geocoding API

Thanks problem solved.