# Direction Api not working in Android google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working with google map in may application. Map Show two addresses or places and draw line between them. So i used direction api in google map. This Project also link with billing account. But some time its give error This api  project is not authorized to use  this  api. some time its work

what is the problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994634/this-api-project-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-please-ensure-that-this-api

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994634/this-api-project-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-please-ensure-that-this-api)