# this api project is not authorized to use this API

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I made a taxi booking project that uses google maps api to locate cabs, pickup and drop locations.

The problem is when I request a ride the following error occurs:

```
This API project is not authorized to use this API
```

Note that I had enabled all google map api services then regenerate the key and the problem is still exist.

How to solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994634/this-api-project-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-please-ensure-that-this-api

Comment: I already saw this solution, and enabled the geocoding and geolocation api services, but the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer,

The problem was in my code at this line:

```
public void requestDirection() {

        snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, getString(R.string.fare_calculating), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snackbar.show();
        GoogleDirection.withServerKey(getString(R.string.google_api_key))
                .from(origin)
                .to(destination)
                .transportMode(TransportMode.DRIVING)
                .execute(this);

        confirm.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

`R.string.google_api_key's` value was feeded by another key from `strings.xml`. For now, I gave a direct value to **withServerKey** until I found the the problem with my `strings.xml.`

```
public void requestDirection() {

        snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, getString(R.string.fare_calculating), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snackbar.show();
        GoogleDirection.withServerKey("[api key]")//getString(R.string.google_api_key))
                .from(origin)
                .to(destination)
                .transportMode(TransportMode.DRIVING)
                .execute(this);

        confirm.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable the required APIs in the google Developer console : https://console.developers.google.com/

Select your project on the Top Left corner and then click on the "ENABLE API AND SERVICES" button in the dashboard.

Note that you may need to enable more than 1 API (Directions, Geolocating,Geocoding etc) based on your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you think you have enabled all, Then you may missed changing your `manifest.xml` file like :

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Add these tags under `application` tag

Comment: I add those tag, rebuild/clean the project, but the problem still exist :(

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue if you hit polyline Api:

https://console.developers.google.com/google/maps-apis/apis/directions-backend.googleapis.com/metrics?project=light-router-266008

Need to enable the APIs:

1. GeoLocation API
2. Directions API