# Google Map Request Denied Trouble

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps, laravel-5, google-api

I am trying to activate google maps on the page. I install [composer API](https://github.com/alexpechkarev/google-maps) without problem. And added my server/domain IP in google API. checked and added the API key into config file.
After that set the Controller and the Route which is like below.

My Route:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@map');
```

Here is my Controller:

```
public function map()
{
    $response = \GoogleMaps::load('geocoding')
        ->setParam(['address' => 'tokyo'])
        ->get();

    return view('welcome', compact('response'));
}
```

And I am calling it on my view:

```
{{ isset($response) ? $response : '' }}
```

But I'm gettin this error?

> { "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this
>   API.", "results" : [], "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" }

Any idea why is this happening?
Do I need to add some script on view? 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you check this anwser? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994634/this-api-project-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-please-ensure-that-this-api

Comment: yea I checked it already but no effects on mine. Do i need to add some script on the view?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Developer Console -> APIs & auth -> APIs
Enable Google Maps Geocoding and Google Maps Geolocation API

Comment: it s actually no effects already enabled the geocoding. But when I calling api on view do I need to add some script?