# Place API PLACES_API_KEY_INVALID

Tags: google-places-api

I want to use Places API, example:

```
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA&key=AIzaSyCOurENeDiNJ4x....." allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

I always get error: "Google Maps Platform rejected your request. This API project is not authorized to use this API."

Key is valid and payments/billings are enabled, any suggestions?

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LIDR.png)

Comment: Possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994634/this-api-project-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-please-ensure-that-this-api

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994634/this-api-project-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-please-ensure-that-this-api)

Comment: You should enable Google Maps Embed API in your project.

Comment: @xomena Thank You. I enabled Google Maps Embed API and it works.