# You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs error when directly entering into address bar

Tags: google-maps

I get an error like so:

```
{
   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Whenever I run this: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Winnetka&key=AIzaSyCKyVbBzwtgkyuut7P5mxK9vcOWMygCfp0`

In the sample video that I am following, he gets a result like so:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an API key. Otherwise it won't work.

To get an API Key you have to go to this webpage https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/#get-started and pick the products you need. Also select or create a project and finally you have to set up a billing account. Unfortunately it isn't for free as far as I know.

Answer (score 12):

in my case i had # in address link `input=City Clinical # 89`so i had to remove it

Comment: Just to clarify. I AM USING AN API KEY and I still got the ERROR because of `#` in my address. After removing `#`, as this answer suggests, I had no problems.

Comment: Could you explain, why # cause the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Post Values like below:

```
  String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;
    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=true";
    String mode = "mode=driving";
    String key = "key="+getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key);
    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor + "&" + mode + "&" + key;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;
```

Answer (score 2):

Read Google's developer page instructions on the [Required parameters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#geocoding), might help.

Comment: I did what it says in the document but still a no go. Please see my edits.

Comment: @Ibanez1408 you might have to enable few APIs, see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994634/this-api-project-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-please-ensure-that-this-api). Also, try not to put your API key in here

Answer (score 1):

Google states

> "As of June 11, 2018, you must enable billing with a credit card and have a valid API key for all of your projects."

https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/?hl=en

and

> "You must have a valid API key and a billing account to access our APIs. When you enable billing, you will get $200 free usage every month for Maps, Routes, or Places."

https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/account-changes/?hl=en