# Getting Distance between two location using Google API. PHP

Tags: javascript, php, google-api

I m trying to calculate distance between two location using API key and PHP as well. I tried two different codes that i found online. both of them have some sort of problem.

Two codes, the first one has an error message as  "This API project is not authorized to use this API.", while the other code doesn't calculate the distance at all.

Code :1

```
<?php

function getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, $unit = ''){
    // Google API key
    $apiKey = 'my key';

    // Change address format
    $formattedAddrFrom    = str_replace(' ', '+', $addressFrom);
    $formattedAddrTo     = str_replace(' ', '+', $addressTo);

    // Geocoding API request with start address
    $geocodeFrom = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$formattedAddrFrom.'&sensor=false&key='.$apiKey);
    $outputFrom = json_decode($geocodeFrom);
    if(!empty($outputFrom->error_message)){
        return $outputFrom->error_message;
    }

    // Geocoding API request with end address
    $geocodeTo = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$formattedAddrTo.'&sensor=false&key='.$apiKey);
    $outputTo = json_decode($geocodeTo);
    if(!empty($outputTo->error_message)){
        return $outputTo->error_message;
    }

    // Get latitude and longitude from the geodata
    $latitudeFrom    = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitudeFrom    = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
    $latitudeTo        = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitudeTo    = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

    // Calculate distance between latitude and longitude
    $theta    = $longitudeFrom - $longitudeTo;
    $dist    = sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * sin(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) +  cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist    = acos($dist);
    $dist    = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles    = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;

    // Convert unit and return distance
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);
    if($unit == "K"){
        return round($miles * 1.609344, 2).' km';
    }elseif($unit == "M"){
        return round($miles * 1609.344, 2).' meters';
    }else{
        return round($miles, 2).' miles';
    }
}

$addressFrom = 'New Jersey, United States';
$addressTo   = 'New York, USA';

// Get distance in km
$distance = getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, "K");

echo $distance;

?>
```

Code :2 -

```
<?php

$from = "New Jersey, United States";
$to = "New York, USA";

$from = urlencode($from);
$to = urlencode($to);

$data = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$from&destinations=$to&language=en-EN&sensor=false");
$data = json_decode($data);

$time = 0;
$distance = 0;

foreach($data->rows[0]->elements as $road) {
    $time += $road->duration->value;
    $distance += $road->distance->value;
}

echo "To: ".$data->destination_addresses[0];
echo "<br/>";
echo "From: ".$data->origin_addresses[0];
echo "<br/>";
echo "Time: ".$time." seconds";
echo "<br/>";
echo "Distance: ".$distance." meters";

?>
```

Code 3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Calculate the distance between two locations</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
       <style type="text/css">
            .formbg { background-color: #66CCFF; padding: 10px 0 10px 20px; color: #191919;
                    border-radius: 10px;  border: 2px solid #6D0839; width: 780px; margin: 0 auto;
            }
       label { font-size: 18px; }
       h1 {color: #003366;}
       </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php 
      function getRouteDistance($source_adrs, $dest_adrs, $unit){
          //Send request and receive json data
          $s_geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$source_adrs.'&sensor=false');
          $s_latlong = json_decode($s_geocode);
          $d_geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$dest_adrs.'&sensor=false');
          $d_latlong = json_decode($d_geocode);
          //Get latitude and longitude
          $lat1 = $s_latlong->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
          $long1 = $s_latlong->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
          $lat2 = $d_latlong->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
          $long2 = $d_latlong->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

          //Calculate distance from latitude and longitude
          $theta = $long1 - $long2;
          $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
          $dist = acos($dist);
          $dist = rad2deg($dist);
          $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515; 
          $unit = strtoupper($unit);
          if ($unit == "K") {
              return ($miles * 1.609344).' KM';
          } else {
              return $miles.' MI';
          }
      } 
      ?>
      <div class="form-group row formbg">
          <?php
          if(($_POST['source'] != '') && ($_POST['destination'] != '')) {
              $source = $_POST['source'];
              $destination = $_POST['destination'];
              $unit = $_POST['unit'];
              $source_adrs = str_replace(' ', '+', $source);
              $dest_adrs = str_replace(' ', '+', $destination);
              $distance = getRouteDistance($source_adrs, $dest_adrs, $unit);
              if($distance != '') {
                echo 'Distance Between <b>'.$source.'</b> and <b>'.$destination.' : </b><b>'.$distance.'</b>'
                    .'<br/><br/>';
              }
          }
          ?>
          <form action="" method="post">
             <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xs-3 col-form-label">Enter Source Address: </label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="source" value="" placeholder="Source">
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xs-3 col-form-label">Enter Destination Address: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="destination" value="" placeholder="Destination">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                 <label class="col-xs-3 col-form-label">Unit: </label>
                 <div class="col-sm-5">
                  <select name="unit" class="form-control">
                      <option value="k">Kilometer</option>
                      <option value="m">Mile</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group row">
                 <label class="col-xs-3 col-form-label"> </label>
                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                   <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
          </form>
      </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't show your private Google API key. I advice you to delete your post and post again your question without the key (because we can see it in edit changes logs)

Comment: For the first issue, have you tried the correct answer for this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994634/this-api-project-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-please-ensure-that-this-api

Comment: "This API project is not authorized to use this API.",  means that you didnt enable that api in your project on Google Developer console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example function:

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * 
  cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
    return ($miles * 0.8684);
  } else {
    return $miles;
  }
}
```

Units are K->Kilometers, M->Miles or N->Nautical Miles

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks the response. but i m trying to get distance by location not lat longs.

Comment: you can get lat and longs by geocoding api. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below link and this not require any google API

https://gist.github.com/bmoren/22470de1cd47410e0902

and if you are trying to get distance by location than use Geo Coding API to get lat lng of particular address and than go through with this link

Comment: Thanks Manish, but i need to calculate distance based on locations not lat longs.

Comment: If you are trying to get distance by location than use Geo Coding API to get lat lng of particular address and than go through with this link