# how we can develop the location auto detect Using html 5?

Tags: html, geolocation

I am developing one webproject and in that project i have requirement that 
there will be one button there named by auto detect and when ever any one 
click on that button visitor will get his location popup in this near textbox,i have created it and seen result in console.

> autodetect.html:44 {error_message: "This API project is not authorized to use >this API.", results: Array(0), status: "REQUEST_DENIED"}

Following is the code for it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Auto detect location</title>
</head>

<body>

    <button onClick="getLocation()">Get Location</button>
    <!--output will display here-->
    <div id="output" style="margin-top: 20px;"></div>
    <div id="output1" style="margin-top: 20px;"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var x = document.getElementById('output');
        var y = document.getElementById('output1');
        x.innerHTML = "Here is output";

        function getLocation() {
            //alert('hi getLocation working');
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                // x.innerHTML = "Supporting..";
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

            } else {
                x.innerHTML = "Sorry your browser not supporting autodetect location.";
            }
        }

        function showPosition(position) {
            // x.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
            // y.innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;

            var locAPI = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=AIzaSyCY2xZxxjq0U6iVzYJetKi9uJZnmIrnPGs&latlng=" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + "&sensor=true";
            // x.innerHTML = locAPI;

            $.get({
                url: locAPI,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });


        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

how we can get code corrected so that we will det displayed this location of the visitos ?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like you don't have a project with the api enabled, maybe this could [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32998566/11871174).Also you shouldn't share your api key [publicly](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices).