# My google maps api key is not functioning in python although it works in swift

Tags: python, api, google-maps, google-places

I use an API key that I got from google maps in my swift project and it works perfectly. When I tried it on python it just gives me an error message. The code that I used and the error message I received are down below.

I [image]already went on the Google cloud platform to get an api key for:
- places api
- map javascript api
- Geolocation api
- Geocoding api

Also with this api key I was not successful.

```py
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='api-key')
geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA')
```

I expect to get the location's id but I'm receiving:
"googlemaps.exceptions.ApiError: REQUEST_DENIED (This API project is not authorized to use this API.)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you are mixing up your IOS API Key with the API key for Web Services? I see there are at least two different 'Get an API Key' articles:

One for Web Services: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key

And one for IOS : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/get-api-key

And if so, the solution is:

- The Python googlemaps library requires the Web Services API Key, and trying to use the IOS API Key will not work.

Sometimes Google will show an API as enabled, but it's actually not enabled. Try disabling and re-enabling the Web Services API key.

Another gotcha is that you might need to enable the Directions API as well.

Comment: @kimo26 What doesn't work? A new API key or the old? Have you enabled it? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994634/this-api-project-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-please-ensure-that-this-api

Comment: I clicked on the link that for the web services that you previously referenced and enabled all these apis: - places api - map javascript api - Geolocation api - Geocoding api and it still doesn't work : "This API project is not authorized to use this API."

Comment: @kimo26 did you also enable the directions api? Again, it seems to me - though I may be wrong - that you will need two different API keys; one for web services and one for ios.

Comment: Not sure exactly what fixed it but hey no problem :)