# Where to Put Google Maps API Key in NodeJS Project

Tags: node.js, google-maps, api-key

I have Google Maps API Key and want to use it with google-distance-matrix library. But i don't know where to put my Key and integrate it with above stated library here is my code

`const distanceAPI = require('google-distance-matrix')`

```
dispatchers.dispatchers.map( (dispatcher) => {
distanceAPI.matrix(dispatcher.location.coordinates, call.pickupLocationCoordinates.coordinates, mode, function(err, distances) {
    
    console.log("distances")
    console.log(distances)
})

})
```

Following error is still being thrown

error = 'You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs.'

I have also create a variable in .env file with following

```
G_API = key
```

Kindly let me know the right way of using the map service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [README.md](https://github.com/ecteodoro/google-distance-matrix#parameters) of google-distance-matrix you have to precise your key in `distance.key()` method.

```
distance.key('myAPIkey');
```

If your using a `.env` file you should call your env variable variable with `process.env` and [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package.

**index.js** :

```
require('dotenv').config();

const distance = require('google-distance-matrix');

distance.key(process.env.MY_API_KEY);

// Working example code
var origins = ['San Francisco CA'];
var destinations = ['New York NY', '41.8337329,-87.7321554'];

distance.matrix(origins, destinations, function (err, distances) {
    if (!err)
        console.log(distances);
})
```

***.env*** :

```
MY_API_KEY=1234AEB
```

You can check a full working example on the google-distance-matrix doc
[here](https://github.com/ecteodoro/google-distance-matrix#example)

Comment: I am getting the following error: This API project is not authorized to use this API.

Comment: You sure , your API key is valid ?

Comment: Does it solves your problem : [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994634/this-api-project-is-not-authorized-to-use-this-api-please-ensure-that-this-api) ?

Comment: Yes its done. Thanks for your input. I had to get the service enabled. After enabling, now it is working.

Comment: Can you accept my answer in order to close the subject ;)

Comment: I dont have required reputation to accept it.

Comment: The reputation is needed to upvote the answer not to accept it.

Comment: Please let me know how to accept the answer. Where to click

Comment: There is a check symbol at the left of my answer. Just below two arrows. A click on it and my answer will be accepted

Comment: checkbox is not visible to me.